# vue js class binding on repetitious element

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-class-components

I wanna create a simple game helps kids to read, in fact it is a language learning approach named 'silent mode', anyway this is the jsfiddle link

https://jsfiddle.net/raminSafari/b7zhc98q/19/

for example if I want a student to read 'pen' first I point to p(1) then e(2) and finally n(3), the code works fine with words which have unique letters, but when the word is something like 'dad' it is not working the way i want, i want it to show d(1)(3), a(2)

here is the complete simplified code(i know it's not robust)

```
<template>
    <div class = "container pt-5 mt-5">
            <h1 class="text-center pb-5"><span style="color: red;"> {{ answer }} </span> just to clarify</h1> <!-- just to clarify -->
    
   

        
        <div class="text-center">
        <template id="keyboard" v-for="alphabet in alphabets" >
            <template v-if = "alphabet == word.first ">
                    <span :class="{ 'active': firstActive, alphabet}"> {{ alphabet }} </span>&nbsp;<strong style="color: red; font-size: 10px;">{{ num1 }}</strong>&nbsp;
            </template>
             <template v-else-if = "alphabet == word.second ">
                   <span :class="{ 'active': secondActive, alphabet}"> {{ alphabet }} </span>&nbsp;<strong style="color: red; font-size: 10px;">{{ num2 }}</strong>&nbsp;
            </template>
             <template v-else-if = "alphabet == word.third ">
                   <span :class="{ 'active': thirdActive, alphabet}"> {{ alphabet }} </span>&nbsp;<strong style="color: red; font-size: 10px;">{{ num3 }}</strong>&nbsp;
            </template>
           
             <template v-else-if = "alphabet == word.forth ">
                   <span :class="{ 'active': forthActive, alphabet}"> {{ alphabet }} </span>&nbsp;<strong style="color: red; font-size: 10px;">{{ num4 }}</strong>&nbsp;
            </template>
             <template v-else-if = "alphabet == word.fifth ">
                   <span :class="{ 'active': forthActive, alphabet}"> {{ alphabet }} </span>&nbsp;<strong style="color: red; font-size: 10px;">{{ num5 }}</strong>&nbsp;
            </template>
            <template v-else>
                <span class="alphabet"> {{ alphabet }} </span>&nbsp;
            </template>
        </template>
       

                 <div><button class = "btn btn-info mt-3" @click = "again">again</button></div>
        </div>
           
            
     </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
     data(){
        return{
         
           alphabets: ["p", "e", "m", "n", "d", "a", "s"],
           firstActive: false,
           secondActive: false,
           thirdActive: false,
           forthActive: false,
           fifthActive: false,
           index: 0,
           words:[
                {
                    first: 'p',
                    second: 'e',
                    third: 'n',
                    forth: '',
                    fifth: '',
                    answer : 'pen'
                },
                {
                    first: 'm',
                    second: 'a',
                    third: 'd',
                    forth: 'e',
                    fifth: '',
                    answer : 'made'
                },
                {
                    first: 'd',
                    second: 'a',
                    third: 'd',
                    forth: '',
                    fifth: '',
                    answer : 'dad'
                },

           ],
           word: [],
            answer: '', 
            myVar1: null,
            myVar2: null,
            myVar3: null,
            myVar4: null,
            myVar5: null,
            num1: '',
            num2: '',
            num3: '',
            num4: '',
            num5: ''
                     
        }
    },

    methods: {

        shuffle(a) {
                for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
                    [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
                }
        
                return a;
            },

            getWord(){
                this.word = this.words[this.index];
                this.answer = this.word.answer;
            },

            again(){
                clearTimeout(this.myVar1);
                clearTimeout(this.myVar2);
                clearTimeout(this.myVar3);
                clearTimeout(this.myVar4);
                clearTimeout(this.myVar5);
                this.firstActive = false;
                this.secondActive = false;
                this.thirdActive = false;
                this.forthActive = false;
                this.fifthActive = false;
                this.num1 = '';
            this.num2 = '';
            this.num3 = '';
            this.num4 = '';
            this.num5 = '';
                if(this.index == this.words.length){
                    this.index = 0;
                }else{
                    this.index++;
                }
                this.getWord();
                this.showBorder();
            },


            showBorder(){
                     this.myVar1 =  setTimeout(() => {
                         this.firstActive = true;
                         this.num1 = 1;
                    }, 2000);

                     this.myVar2 =  setTimeout(() => {
                         this.secondActive = true;
                         this.num2 = 2;
                    }, 4000);

                    this.myVar3 =  setTimeout(() => {
                         this.thirdActive = true;
                         this.num3 = 3;
                    }, 6000);

                    this.myVar4 =  setTimeout(() => {
                         this.forthActive = true;
                         this.num4 = 4;
                    }, 8000);

                    this.myVar5 =  setTimeout(() => {
                         this.fifthActive = true;
                         this.num5 = 5;
                    }, 10000);
            }
       


    },
    

   
     created(){
            
         this.words = this.shuffle(this.words);
         this.getWord();
         this.showBorder();
                                
      }

      



}
</script>

<style>
    span.alphabet{
         display: inline-block;
         width: 70px;
         height: 70px;
        
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: 600;
    }
    .active{
        border: 2px solid red;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
</style>
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is not just a copy-and-paste code and it is a bit long. If you don't want to read that you may just skip to the conclusion.

I read the jsfiddle and here are some suggestions to solve the problem you are facing:

### 1. Treat the numbers as a string, not number

After that, you will know that the d(1)(3) issue is not showing 2 **numbers**, it's indeed *how to append the string "1" and "3"* and display it.

### 2. Divide-and-conquer

Divide your whole task into 3 parts:

1. Create functions to control which alphabet should be highlighted and showing corresponding sequence.
2. Create a component, just to display the alphabet and the sequence e.g. d(1)(3).
3. Define functions to trigger the rendering process and reset the app state.

#### App.vue

This is what the data looks like in `App.vue`

```js
data: function() {
    return {
        word: "dad",
        alphabets: ["p", "e", "m", "n", "d", "a", "s"],
        hits: ["", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
        handlers: [],
        delay: 2000,
    }
},
```

`this.hits` will store the corresponding sequences of the hit. For example, for the case of *dad*, the hits will **eventually** become: `["", "", "", "", "13", "2", ""]`.

These are the functions you should have in `App.vue`

- loop each char. in `this.word`, and do corresponding rendering

```js
renderAnswer: function() {
    var self = this;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.word.length; i++) {
        self.doSetTimeout(i, self);
    }
}
```

- control when to do the rendering

```js
doSetTimeout: function (i, self) {
    self.handlers.push(setTimeout(function () { 
        self.updateHits(i, self) 
    }, self.delay * i));
}
```

- update the `hits` array, and this will trigger corresponding rendering on each alphabet

```js
updateHits: function(i, self) {
    let char = self.word[i];
    let index = self.alphabets.indexOf(char);
    console.debug(char, index)
    self.hits[index] += (i + 1);
    self.hits = self.hits.filter(x => true); // force refresh list for binding
}
```

Divide your big function into some smaller functions and let each of them just doing **1** thing.

Note: Here, you will see `renderAnswer()` calls `doSetTimeout()` and `doSetTimeout()` calls `updateHits()`. In order to get the data and functions correctly, we need to define `var self = this` and pass `self` to each function call.

#### Sub-component for the alphabet

In the template of App.vue, you need to define a `<alphabet>` sub-component. This component is solely responsible for render a particular alphabet and the sequence related to that alphabet.

```
<alphabet 
    v-for="(char, index) in alphabets" 
    v-bind:key="char" 
    :alphabet="char" 
    v-bind:hits="hits[index]"
/>
```

You need to pass the alphabet and the corresponding hit value to the sub-component in order to render the component properly. The code of this sub-component should be straight-forward so I will skip it here. You may need to know how to pass and use `props` from the [official documentaion](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) when doing this part.

#### Run the app

When you set up all the functions and the sub-component, you should be able to render `dad`'s case when you trigger `renderAnswer()`.

#### Reset the status

You may need to reset the app status for each new word. Therefore, you should also define a `reset()` function to update `this.word` into a new word, and reset each item in `this.hits` as empty string.

Read [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bemnlam/aa6548a1c95f42c06fa99ac707d200c5) if you need more details of the above steps.

### Conclusion

When you are facing some problem on coding, you can try to re-phasing the problem you met. **Asking the right questions** will lead you to solve them using a better approach.

On the other hand, **break down the problem into smaller problems and tackle them one by one**. In this case, try to split the big function into some smaller and simpler functions. And, try to create a sub-component to do the rendering part while leave all the logic to its parent.

Hope you can solve the problem you met and help more kids :)

Answer (score 0):

You may store your letter inputs in an array, in that way, you can get the indexes of the letters inputed and display them. I would recommend to structure your code like this. Here's the fiddle of the refactored code https://jsfiddle.net/tk41d0wo/

```
<div id="app">
  <div>
    Current word is <span style="color: red;">{{ words[currentIndex] }}</span>
  </div>
  <div>
     <button 
       v-for="letter in letters" 
       :key="letter" 
       @click="inputLetter(letter)"
       :style="{ color: (inputs.includes(letter)) ? 'red': 'initial' }"
     >
       {{ letter }} <small>({{ getAllLetterPositions(letter).join(', ') }})</small>
     </button>
  </div>
  <button @click="resetInputs">
    Reset
  </button>
</div>
```

and in your component...

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    currentIndex: 0,
    words: ['made', 'sad', 'dad'],
    letters: ['p', 'e', 'm', 'n', 'd', 'a', 's'],
    inputs: [],
  },
  methods: {
    inputLetter(letter) {
      this.inputs.push(letter);
        if(this.inputs.join('') == this.words[this.currentIndex]) {
        this.currentIndex++;
        this.resetInputs();
      }
    },
    getAllLetterPositions(letter) {
        return this.inputs.reduce((positions, current, index) => {
        if(current == letter) {
            return positions.concat(index + 1);
        }
        return positions;
      }, []).sort(function(a, b){return a-b})
    },
    resetInputs() {
        this.inputs = [];
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: thanks @rjcarf but that's not what i want, i said code works fine with words which have unique letters, programs shows the number for example m(1), a(2) and n(3) and first grade student figures out its 'man', but you give me an idea to create another new and simple game, thanks

Comment: Glad you liked it @RaminSafari . I was meant to refactor your code also to make it shorter and less complicated but anyway, happy coding.